# Defining Right and Left Tables in SQL JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I wanted to ask is there a way to know which table should be right or left while using joins in SQL? for example I have two tables that I am joining, for example,

```
SELECT * FROM filtered_numbers LEFT JOIN telecoms ON filtered_numbers.TelecomID = telecoms.ID
```

Now The 'filtered_numbers' table has 200 records while 'telecoms' has only 5.
My question is that will there be a difference in performance / efficiency of the db if I interchange the position of these two tables in the query?
If yes, why?

Comment: No. And Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: `tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2` is the same as `tbl2 RIGHT JOIN tbl1`.

Comment: In a LEFT JOIN, you get all the rows from the first table and the second table might not have matches for all of them. In a RIGHT JOIN it's the other way around.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the answer. and this was just an example, I don't use right join either.

Comment: @Barmar I know, but my question is about performance

Comment: There's no performance difference. MySQL doesn't care what order you put your joins in.

Comment: There's no difference between `filtered_numbers RIGHT JOIN telecoms` and `telecoms LEFT JOIN filtered_numbers`.

Comment: There IS a difference between `filtered_numbers RIGHT JOIN telecoms` and `telecoms RIGHT JOIN filtered_numbers` since they produce different results.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for clarification . Helped a lot.

Comment: And most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a little complicated.  The first thing to note is that

```
FROM filtered_numbers LEFT JOIN
     telecoms
     ON filtered_numbers.TelecomID = telecoms.ID
```

is semantically quite different from:

```
FROM telecoms LEFT JOIN
     filtered_numbers
     ON filtered_numbers.TelecomID = telecoms.ID
```

Switching only the tables changes the meaning of the query.  The execution plan and performance will be different.  You will get the same query if you change the `LEFT JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN` in this case, but as Strawberry points out, `LEFT JOIN` is much preferred.

This is *simplified* though and not always true.  If you have a complicated query, the ordering of the `JOIN`s *can* make a difference.  Now, `LEFT JOIN` has a "driving" table (where all rows are kept) so there are many fewer options.  But if you have `INNER JOIN`s, then ordering *can* matter.

In fact, it can matter so much that MySQL offers [optimizer hints just to control join order](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-join-order).

So, the answer to your question is:

- Switching the tables in your query will affect performance because the meaning of the query changes.
- Switching the tables and changing to a `RIGHT JOIN` will not affect performance because there is really only one option for the optimizer.
- In more complex queries, the ordering of joins can be important.

Comment: Thank You so much. This was the answer I was looking for.